# Connect to specific route via socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I need to access Web sockets via specific path, I mount my socket.io on the client with a path ('ws')
Server code:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {path: '/notif'});
```

Client code:

```
var socket = io('//127.0.0.1:7733/ws/', {path: '/notif'});
socket.connect();
```

This does not work due to “ws” on client. I suspect it's because I don't have the equivalent on the server (e.g. require server on specific path).
(when removing the /rt mount, everything seems to work as expected).

What is the server api to set up ws to listen on specific URL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you know what `/ws/` in your url is used for?

Here you are asking to connect to the `ws` namespace.
To receive connection for that namespace on the server you have to write:

```
io.of('/ws').on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('someone connected');
});
```

See: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Also you don't need to call `socket.connect();`

Calling `io()` or `io.connect()` will already try to establish connection with the server.

Comment: /ws/ in my case if really just a hint for my load balancer to route the request to the correct server.

Comment: Then I think you should have this on your client: `io('//127.0.0.1:7733', { path: '/ws/notif' })` and set the same path on the server depending whether or not your balancer rewrites the path