# Node.js Net.Socket() to connect to net.tcp web service

Tags: node.js

So I have a web service running on port 7001 over TCP on:

> net.tcp://www.myurl.com:7001/my/webservice

and I want to connect to it using net.Socket:

```
client.connect(7001, 'myurl.mine.com/my/webservice', function () {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write(msg);
});
```

When i do the above, it gives an exception:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <<my url>>
     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onLookup [as oncomplete]
```

when i try connect to it without the /my/webservice, it connects fine and doesnt give an error at the client.connect() stage, but obviously cant find that endpoint so it gives another error when i try to do the client.write()

Any one any idea how to use net.Socket against a web service with a url that isnt just myurl.com:7001 but actually contains a route like myurl.com:7001/my/webservice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to specific route via socket.io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865884/connect-to-specific-route-via-socket-io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/net.html#net_net_connect_port_host_connectlistener) the version of the method you are using expects only a *hostname* for a second argument. You are providing *hostname + path*

In your case I would recommend using [a more generalized version](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/net.html#net_net_connect_options_connectlistener) of net.connect which accepts an object with parameters. So your code will look something like this:

```
client.connect({
        host: 'myurl.mine.com',
        port: 7001,
        path: '/my/webservice'
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Connected');
        client.write(msg);
    }
);
```